# Make these following numbers print to screen with a loop, with an increasing value of 3?

Tags: c++

I need these numbers to print to screen using a loop : 1,4,7,10,13,16. They are all increasing by three I was only able to create the program to show all numbers between 1 and 16 not just the increasing values of 3. How could I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int input;
    for (int input = 1; input <= 10; input++) {
        std::cout << "\n" << input;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `input += 3` instead of `input++`

Comment: @OP Were you aware that you can increment the loop counter by a value other than 1?

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num += 3) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `// This is the c++ way to get a newline`  actually its a new line + a flush of the output stream. `'\n'` or `"\n"` would be fine if you don't need the flush.